# How to find items in a lightbox / fancybox with Capybara

Tags: html, css, ruby, cucumber, capybara

So with my lightbox recognized, how do I access what is inside of it?

When I type:

```
within("div.fancybox-wrap.fancybox-desktop.fancybox-type-iframe.fancybox-opened") do
    within(:xpath, "//table[@id='small_calendar'][0]") do
        page.find('td', :text => '5').click
    end
end
```

For

```
<table id="small_calendar">
```

I get...

```
Unable to find xpath "//table[@id='small_calendar'][0]" (Capybara::Element
NotFound)
```

Modified search....

```
sleep(10)
within("div.fancybox-wrap.fancybox-desktop.fancybox-type-iframe.fancybox-opened") do
    within_frame('fancybox-frame') do
        #within(:xpath, ".//table[@id='small_calendar'][0]") do
            page.find(:xpath, ".//table[@id='small_calendar'][0]/td[@text='5']").click
        #end
    end
end
```

gets me this bug...

```
  findElements execution failed;
   Element does not exist in cache (Selenium::WebDriver::Error::StaleElement
ReferenceError)
```

Comment: Can you please add the html of the page - both the page and the iframe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it!

The problem seems to be that within-frame and xpath do not get along.  Once I removed it from the equation, I got the desired result.

```
within_frame('fancybox-frame') do
    #within(:xpath, ".//table[@id='small_calendar'][0]") do #chokes
    within(all("table[id='small_calendar']").first) do  #works!
         #page.find(:xpath, ".//table[@id='small_calendar'][0]/td[@text='5']").click #chokes
         page.find("td[id='2013_0_6']").click #works!
    end
end
```

Comment: I believe it was the "[0]" that was messing up the inner within's xpath. I believe by default, it picks the first matching element, so you do not need it, which is why I had removed it in my original answer. :)

Answer (score 1):

If the elements are within a frame, you have to explicitly state that by using the `within_frame` method:

```
within_frame('fancybox-frame') do
    within(:xpath, "//table[@id='small_calendar']") do
        page.find('td', :text => '5').click
    end
end
```

Comment: Close!  I'm now seeing...  `      findElements execution failed;
       Element does not exist in cache (Selenium::WebDriver::Error::StaleElement
ReferenceError)`

Comment: ` findElements execution failed; Element does not exist in cache (Selenium::WebDriver::Error::StaleElement ReferenceError)`

Comment: It looks like you cannot use the `within_frame` method within another `within` block. Try removing the `within("div.fancybox-wrap...)` part.

Comment: removing the wrapping within gets me an element not found.  removing the core within gets me the StaleElement

Comment: Doing both get's me element not found :(